# Why function says unused argument (FcastTill = FcastTillDate)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a function that takes 3 arguments one of them is a Date.
The function keeps telling me Unused Argument but I am using it actually.

```
Warning: Error in F: unused argument (FcastTill = FcastTillDate)


F <- function(numberDaysForecast,FcastTill, supply_pivot_table){
  dates <- as.Date(supply_pivot_table$Day)
  maxDate = max(dates)
  forward_values = FcastTill - maxDate
  for (i in 1:forward_values) {
    newdates = maxDate + i
    dates = c(dates,newdates)
  }
  
  #......Some other Code ......
  
  return(SomeValues)
}
```

Comment: Please show us the call to `F` that is generating the error.

Comment: res=F(numberDaysForecast = x,FcastTill = FcastTillDate,supply_pivot_table=PivotDataSupply())

Comment: you have used brackets in ````supply_pivot_table=PivotDataSupply()````. PivotDataSupply now looks like a function for which it is expecting arguments. From the rest of your code, PivotDataSupply seems to be a dataframe. Remove the brackets  ````supply_pivot_table=PivotDataSupply```` should work

Comment: Looking at your data, if you `class(the thing I put in second position)` in the `F <- function(`, is it a date? And what package is this function in?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's my error. I was actually modifying another file with the same name in my project.